# How to use the Cython extension on Jupiter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, cython

I am trying to use the Cython extension of the Jupiter Notebook, but it's not working.
I first installed Cython on my anaconda environment:

```
conda install Cython
```

and then I opened up a Jupyter notebook and made a new file (`untitled1.py`)
and then I imported the Cython extension:

```
%load_ext Cython
```

and I tried to execute the code below:

```
%cython

cpdef int ncov = 8
```

but this generates an error, namely:

```
    cpdef int ncov = 8
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I use the Cython extension on the Jupiter notebook?

Thank you,

Comment: I don't think `cpdef int ncov` is actually meaningful. It compiles, but looks to behave the same way as `cdef int`. `cpdef` is really designed for functions, not variables.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by inserting

```
%%cython
```

instead of

```
%cython
```